# Show in template fields labels names instead of fields names - Django

Tags: django, forms, templates

I use to display errors from the forms.py in template using the code below:

```
{% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Error:</strong> {% if key != '__all__' %}{{ key|title  }} {% endif %} - {{ value|striptags }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

But my project is in a different language so I don't want to show the field name but the label name.

I need something like taht

```
{{ key.label|title  }}


{% for key, value in form.errors.items %}
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
  <strong>Error:</strong> {% if key != '__all__' %}{{ key.label|title  }} {% endif %} - {{ value|striptags }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Forms

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MedicalPatient
        fields = {'name', ...
                  }
        labels = {'name': '',
                  ...'
                  }
```

How to show label names instead of field names?

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the form fields and access the label and any errors from the bound field itself

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  {% for error in field.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <strong>Error:</strong>{{ field.label }} - {{ error }}
    </div>
  {% endfor }
{% endfor %}
```

This would mean you would have to handle non field errors separately

```
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    <strong>Error:</strong>{{ error }}
  </div>
{% endfor }
```

I think the assumption is that field errors are usually rendered right next to the field they are for so the `form.errors` dict is pretty barebones

Comment: Thank you, but your solution doesn't show the name of the label. The field name has not been replaced. I have no value. Only shows the alert. I added a forms template in my question. I would be grateful for your suggestion on how to show the field name.